# Write a query to find all movies where Actor 1 and Actor 2 work together in Neo4j database with Gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin-server

My database structure is shown in following image
[image: database structure]

I want to search all the Movie title in which Actor 1 (id = 5) and Actor 2 (id = 11) works together.

I don't understand how to compare movie title to itself in and condition

Comment: I started with following few queries, but don't understand how to proceed with `and` condition

Comment: `gremlin> :> g.V().outE('ACTS_IN').or(outV().has('id','5'),outV().has('id','11')).inV().values('title')`
`gremlin> :> g.V().outE('ACTS_IN').and(or(outV().has('id','5'),outV().has('id','11'))).inV().values('title')`
`gremlin> :> g.V().outE('ACTS_IN').and(outV().has('id',within('5','11'))).inV().values('title')`
`gremlin> :> g.V().outE('ACTS_IN').and(outV().has('id',within('5','11')),).inV().values('title')`

Answer (score 0):

You could try in the following way:

```
 Match (a:Actor)--(m:Movie)--(b:Actor)
 When m.title='Gremlin'
 Return a,b
```

Comment: For Cypher instead of Gremlin, almost, but you're missing the restriction on the ids of the actors, and we don't know the title. You would need to use the following for the WHERE clause: `... WHERE id(a) = 5 AND id(b) = 11 RETURN m.title as title`